# Incorrect json output from csv input

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have this csv input which has itemnumber as key field as each itemnumber will be assigned with 2
house-id. so i want my json output to be generated as below. where, itemnumber will be unique and under that there should be details which is an array of objects that contains 2 houseid assigned for itemnumber.

```
Key,Code,Type,ItemNumber,OnHand,Time,quantity,onOrder,houseId,TimeStamp 
1,US,F,67,8,10-23-2000,0,0,010,2022-05-04 08:48:11 
1,US,F,67,8,10-23-2000,0,0,011,2022-05-04 08:48:11 
1,US,F,68,8,10-23-2000,0,0,010,2022-05-04 08:48:11 
1,US,F,68,8,10-23-2000,0,0,011,2022-05-04 08:48:11 
1,US,F,69,8,10-23-2000,0,0,010,2022-05-04 08:48:11 
1,US,F,69,8,10-23-2000,0,0,011,2022-05-04 08:48:11
```

Expected output in JSON: I want to generated an output where Details will be based on `ItemNumber`. for each `ItemNumber`, there will be assigned 2 house ids.

```
{
  "price": {
    "Key": "1",
    "Code": "US",
    "Type": "F",
    "Details": [
      {
        "ItemNumber": "67",
        "Date": "10-23-2000",
        "Details": [
          {
            "OnHand": "8",
            "Quantity": "0",
            "houseDetails": {
              "houseId": "010"
            }
          },
          {
            "OnHand": "8",
            "Quantity": "0",
            "houseDetails": {
              "houseId": "011"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ItemNumber": "68",
        "Date": "10-23-2000",
        "Details": [
          {
            "OnHand": "8",
            "Quantity": "0",
            "houseDetails": {
              "houseId": "010"
            }
          },
          {
            "OnHand": "8",
            "Quantity": "0",
            "houseDetails": {
              "houseId": "011"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ItemNumber": "69",
        "Date": "10-23-2000",
        "Details": [
          {
            "OnHand": "8",
            "Quantity": "0",
            "houseDetails": {
              "houseId": "010"
            }
          },
          {
            "OnHand": "8",
            "Quantity": "0",
            "houseDetails": {
              "houseId": "011"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The output that you have provided is not a valid JSON. Update it to make the question more understandable

Comment: @HarshankBansal  i updated the ouput with right format. thx

Comment: Will all the rows have same value for `Key`? what I mean is in the example CSV all rows have same values for `Key`.  If they are different then you will need a JSON Array as output not JSON Object.

Comment: Your input only has one house id. Where is the second house id coming from?

Comment: The time in your Json output also do not match your input. Where are they coming from?

Comment: Basically, the key will be same however, for each ItemNumber there will be 2 house-id. so i want to generate an output as shown above. for each ItemNumber there will be 2 house-id ynder details as an array of object

Comment: The time in your Json output also do not match csv. Where are they coming from? Is it from the Time field in the csv?

Comment: @HarshankBansal can you check now, i ve updated it with right values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your required output using `groupBy` function. This function takes an Array as input, and a function to get the field on which you want to group your payload. So in your case, you need to group your payload on the basis of the `ItemNumber` key.

You can read more about this function on the [official documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-groupby) to understand the solution better.

After that you just need a simple `map` function to map to your required format.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
{
  Key: payload[0].Key,
  Code: payload[0].Code,
  "Type": payload[0].Type,
  Details: payload groupBy $.ItemNumber 
            pluck $ 
            map ((item) -> {
                ItemNumber: item[0].ItemNumber,
                Time: item[0].Time,
                Details: item map ((itemDetail) -> {
                OnHand: itemDetail.OnHand,
                Quantity: itemDetail.quantity,
                houseDetails: {
                    houseId: itemDetail.houseId
                }
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: thank you, it was exactly the requested output. Thx